# connect nodes at same level of an binary tree

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, tree

I have seen some articles/pages on how to connect the nodes of an binary tree which are at same level but none of those articles explain the process/algorithm clearly. I would appreciate if someone can take this up. Code is not necessary, but explaining it with pseudo will be nice.

For the sake of discussion, let us consider tree as:

```
               0
           1        2
        3     4   5    6
    7                      9
```

In above case:

```
0 should point to null.
1 should point to 2.
3 should point to 4.
....
7 should point to 9.
9 should point to NULL.
```

Basic tree structure is:

```
class Tree {
  public:
    int data;
    Tree* left;
    Tree* right;
    Tree* next;
}
```

Comment: You can Traverse the tree levelwise using [Breadth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) Algorithm and on every level you can temporaryily store a previous node. Then the `next` of  `previous node` will be `currently parsed` node.

Comment: Yes, use bfs or breadth first search which traverses in layers , so basically you will have nodes at the same level at the same distance from the root.

Comment: @sameerkn, I understand that. Would you mind writing pseudo code please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an interesting approach that doesn't use extra memory, which is sort of inductive:

1. The first level is already connected (it only has one node)
2. Let's say level `i` is connected. Then to connect level `i+1` do the following:

   a) Initialize node `lst` (just an intermediate variable we will use later) to `null`

   b) Start at the first node on level `i`.

   c) Traverse nodes on level `i` starting from the first node. Note that you can easily traverse nodes on level `i` because it is already connected, so you have sibling pointers in each node.

   d) For each node on level `i` look first at its left child, then at its right child. For each child that is not null, if `lst` is not `null`, connect `lst` to that child. Then set `lst` to that child.

Once you connected level `i + 1`, you can move on to the next level. If after traversing the level `lst` is still null, it means that no node on this level had a child => this was the last level, you can stop the algorithm.

It is easy to show why this works, it takes linear time and constant space, so it is strictly better than BFS with a queue (which takes linear memory).

Comment: A variant on this is to simply use the node themselves as the queue items by using their next pointer. We only need to keep a pointer to the next end of row because when the end of the current row is processed, the tail of the queue points to the end of the next row.

Answer (score 1):

Following Ishamael's idea, I'd suggest a procedure along the lines of

```
void link_levels(Tree* t){
    Tree *head, *tail, *end_of_row;
    assert (t != 0);
    t->next = 0;
    head = tail = end_of_row = t;
    while(head != 0){
        if(head->left != 0){
            tail->next = head->left;
            tail = tail->next;
            tail->next = 0;
        }
        if(head->right != 0){
            tail->next = head->right;
            tail = tail->next;
            tail->next = 0;
        }
        if(head == end_of_row){
            head = head->next;
            end_of_row->next = 0;
            end_of_row = tail;
        }
        else {
            head = head->next;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use BFS as suggested in the comments.
Then you will have each node's distance from the root.

pseudo code:

```
 vis[1..n] = false   // mark each node as un-visited
 dis[1..n] = 0
 Queue q
 dis[root] = 0 
 vis[root] = true
 q.push(root)
 while !q.empty()
     node x = q.front()
     children[] = children nodes of node x
     for each child in children 
          !vis[child] 
            dis[child] = dis[x] + 1 
            vis[child] =true 
            q.enqueue(child)
     q.pop()
```

Now you will have each nodes distance from root, aggregate each node based on the distance , and can join the nodes as per your requirements.

Comment: The nodes can be linked together in the same loop because they'll appear in the queue in the order 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 9.